# listview itemclick set text to textview issue

Tags: android, listview

In my listview, when I long press row 1 it should change the amount of a textview in row 1. However I have a problem, when I try to change the amount of the specific row (example: row 1), the 5th row of the listview also changes. Also, when the listview is recycled, the textview returns to its old value. Been trying to solve this for a day already but to no luck.

Any help is appreciated!

```
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View mView = convertView;
        String betid = mData.get(i).get("id");
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (mView == null) {
            Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tx_number = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tx_number);
            holder.tx_amount = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tx_amount);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) mView.findViewById(R.id.checkmark);
            holder.tx_status = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tx_status);

            holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
                        checked.add((Integer) holder.checkBox.getTag());
                        holder.tx_amount.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bluelim));
                        holder.tx_number.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bluelim));
                        holder.tx_status.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bluelim));
                    } else {
                        holder.tx_amount.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        holder.tx_number.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        holder.tx_status.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    }
                }
            });

            listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    TextView txAmt = view.findViewById(R.id.tx_amount);
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    alert.setTitle("Enter New Amount:");
                    final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                    input.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);
                    alert.setView(input);
                    alert.setPositiveButton("enter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            String zzx = input.getText().toString();
                            txAmt.setText(zzx);
                            holder.tx_status.setText(zzx);
                            holder.tx_amount.setText(zzx);
                        }
                    });
                    alert.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            //Put actions for CANCEL button here, or leave in blank
                        }
                    });
                    alert.show();

                    return true;
                }

            mView.setTag(holder);
            holder.checkBox.setTag(i);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) mView.getTag();
            ((ViewHolder) mView.getTag()).checkBox.setTag(i);
        }

        if (betid != null) {
            String betnumber = mData.get(i).get("betnumber");
            String amountTarget = mData.get(i).get("betamount");
            String status = mData.get(i).get("status");
            holder.tx_amount.setText(amountTarget);
            holder.tx_number.setText(betnumber);
            holder.tx_status.setText(status);
        }



        ViewHolder holde2r = (ViewHolder) mView.getTag();
        for (int k = 0; k < checked.size(); k++) {
            if (checked.get(k) == i) {
                holde2r.checkBox.setChecked(true);
            } else if (checked.get(k) != i) {
                holde2r.checkBox.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
        return mView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView tx_number;
        TextView tx_amount;
        TextView tx_status;
        CheckBox checkBox;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this. please add this two methods if not added

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   return position;
}
```

Add notifyDataSetChange on positive button click listener.

```
 listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    TextView txAmt = view.findViewById(R.id.tx_amount);
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    alert.setTitle("Enter New Amount:");
                    final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                    input.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);
                    alert.setView(input);
                    alert.setPositiveButton("enter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            String zzx = input.getText().toString();
                            txAmt.setText(zzx);
                            holder.tx_status.setText(zzx);
                            holder.tx_amount.setText(zzx);



adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



                        }
                    });
                    alert.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            //Put actions for CANCEL button here, or leave in blank
                        }
                    });
                    alert.show();

                    return true;
                }
```

Comment: I added this, thanks! now only error is set text doesnt correspond to row clicked.

Comment: hi i have update code try notifydatasetChanged(). if it willnot work try notifydatasetchanged(position)

Comment: I'm getting error: `notifyDataSetChanged( ) 
in BaseAdapter cannot be applied
to
(int)` when i try to use `notifydatasetchanged(position)`

Comment: send me your logcat ...  https://paste.ubuntu.com/  generate link and place here locat link

Comment: <youradaptername>.notifydatasetchanged(position) try it

Comment: still cannot apply `adapter.notifydatasetchanged(position)`. getting same error

Comment: send me your logcat data

Answer (score 0):

you should learn the `listview` lifecycle. however if you want to do that you have to change the item data from the datasource  which in this case , its `mData`. and after updateting the item call `notifyItemchanged()` on adapter to apply the item in listview. the reason for after recycling you see the old data is that the list gets data from `mData` and you just updated the `View`. so instead of geting the viewholder. get item by `position` in longclick and after you updated the item just call `notifyItemChanged(position);`

Comment: trying to apply `notifyItemChanged(position)`, I get an error saying `cannot resolve`.

Answer (score 0):

First you missed `});` in your code before `mView.setTag(holder);`, so your code will have compile issues which I think you should have seen.

Second, you should not call `listView.setOnItemLongClickListener` in `getView`. Because this will repeat many times depends on how many items visible in your screen.

Finally, you should update the data source, i.e.: `mData` in your code, with the latest data, and then call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` to update the UI.

So your code should be something like below:

```java
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    TextView txAmt = view.findViewById(R.id.tx_amount);
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    alert.setTitle("Enter New Amount:");
                    final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                    input.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);
                    alert.setView(input);
                    alert.setPositiveButton("enter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            String zzx = input.getText().toString();
                            // Remove codes below
                            // txAmt.setText(zzx);
                            // holder.tx_status.setText(zzx);
                            // holder.tx_amount.setText(zzx);

                            mData.get(position).setXXX(zzx); // call the setter of your data model
                            adapter.notifyDatasetChanged(); // call this will update the listview with the latest data
                        }
                    });
                    alert.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            //Put actions for CANCEL button here, or leave in blank
                        }
                    });
                    alert.show();

                    return true;
                }
                });


public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View mView = convertView;
        String betid = mData.get(i).get("id");
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (mView == null) {
            Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tx_number = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tx_number);
            holder.tx_amount = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tx_amount);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) mView.findViewById(R.id.checkmark);
            holder.tx_status = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tx_status);

            holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
                        checked.add((Integer) holder.checkBox.getTag());
                        holder.tx_amount.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bluelim));
                        holder.tx_number.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bluelim));
                        holder.tx_status.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bluelim));
                    } else {
                        holder.tx_amount.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        holder.tx_number.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        holder.tx_status.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    }
                }
            });

            mView.setTag(holder);
            holder.checkBox.setTag(i);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) mView.getTag();
            ((ViewHolder) mView.getTag()).checkBox.setTag(i);
        }

        if (betid != null) {
            String betnumber = mData.get(i).get("betnumber");
            String amountTarget = mData.get(i).get("betamount");
            String status = mData.get(i).get("status");
            holder.tx_amount.setText(amountTarget);
            holder.tx_number.setText(betnumber);
            holder.tx_status.setText(status);
        }



        ViewHolder holde2r = (ViewHolder) mView.getTag();
        for (int k = 0; k < checked.size(); k++) {
            if (checked.get(k) == i) {
                holde2r.checkBox.setChecked(true);
            } else if (checked.get(k) != i) {
                holde2r.checkBox.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
        return mView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView tx_number;
        TextView tx_amount;
        TextView tx_status;
        CheckBox checkBox;
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying to apply the `mData.get(position).setXXX(zzx);` to my code, mData directly gets data from the database so I didnt make a model for it.